Selfhosted gitlab not working with non-bundled nginx
I have gitlab-ce running on a centos-stream-9 vm, and nginx running on a separate ubuntu vm, working as a reverse proxy to the gitlab instance. But for some reason it is not working. nginx is returning a 502 Bad Gateway.
The server running nginx is 192.168.0.71, and gitlab is 192.168.0.148
Following this walkthrough on the gitlab website, I updated my gitlab.rb to have the following
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['192.168.0.1/24', '192.168.0.71']
nginx['enable'] = false
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
nginx['listen_port'] = 8084
nginx['listen_https'] = false

My nginx config includes this
server {
    listen 83;
    listen [::]:83;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.148:8084;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
 }


Have you checked logs on both systems? Can you query http://192.168.0.148:8084 OK with curl for instance from the proxy server?
